# Switch from icons to label in the navbar

Tags: html, responsive-design, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have created a website using Bootstrap 3.1.1 and am using the responsive design to allow a collapsable device.

The use cases are:

1. For the desktop version, the navbar should display icons
2. For a smaller width, the dropdown should appear, but use labels instead of icons.

I have created a [JSBin to replicate the scenario](http://jsbin.com/rodoc/2/edit)

Is there a built-in technique for this, or do I move to jQuery to remove the `glyphicon` classes when the collapse occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create 2 div's inside `navbar-collapse div` . One div for display icons the other div for labels. Use `.visible-xs` class on the div with has labels and Use `.visible-sm .visible-md .visible-lg` classes on the div which consists icons for desktop version.

For more detail check [Responsive classes, Bootstrap3](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities)

Code Example

```
<ul class="visible-sm visible-md visible-lg navbar-nav nav">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></span> 
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
    <!-- Smaller screen -->

      <ul class="visible-xs navbar-nav nav ">
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">
          <span>Help</span>
        </a>
      </li>
    </ul>
```